# I have a query about checked list boxes in c#

Tags: c#, listbox, checkedlistbox

I have set up a program that so far can browse for the location of a file that possesses data in a text file holding the locations of other files which then shows me if they exist, are missing or are a duplicate inside listboxes. The next step is to enable the user to select files in the checked list boxes and being given the option to either move or copy. I have already made buttons which allow this but I want to be able to use them for the checked boxes I the list boxes.(p.s) please ignore any comments I have made in the code they are just previous attempts of doing other things in the code.

My code so far:

```
namespace File_existence
{
    public partial class fileForm : Form
    {
        private string _filelistlocation;

        public fileForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void fileForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            _filelistlocation = textBox1.Text;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //GetDuplicates();
            checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox2.Items.Clear();
            ReadFromList();
        }

        private void GetDuplicates()
        {
            DirectoryInfo directoryToCheck = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\\temp");

            FileInfo[] files = directoryToCheck.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            var duplicates = files.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                                .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                                .Select(group => group.Key);
            if (duplicates.Count() > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The file exists");
                FileStream s2 = new FileStream(_filelistlocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                // open _filelistlocation
                // foreach line in _filelistlocation
                // concatenate pat hand filename
                //
            }
        }

        public void ReadFromList()
        {
            int lineCounter = 0;
            int badlineCounter = 0;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_filelistlocation))
            {
                String line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] values = line.Split('\t');
                    if (values.Length == 2)
                    {
                        string fullpath = string.Concat(values[1], "\\", values[0]);
                        if (File.Exists(fullpath))
                            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(fullpath);
                        else
                            listBox2.Items.Add(fullpath);
                        ++lineCounter;
                    }
                    else
                        ++badlineCounter;
                    //Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }


         //StreamReader files= new StreamReader(File)();
         private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

         private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
         {
             FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
             folderBrowserDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
             DialogResult dlgResult = folderBrowserDlg.ShowDialog();
             if (dlgResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
             {
                 textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDlg.SelectedPath;
                 Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = folderBrowserDlg.RootFolder;
             }
             try
             {
                 string fileName = "filetest1.txt";
                 string sourcePath = @"C:\Temp\Trade files\removed";
                 string targetPath = @"C:\Temp\Trade files\queued";
                 string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
                 string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath,fileName);
                 System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
             }

             catch (IOException exc)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
             }
         }


         private void button3_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
         {
             try
             {
                 string sourceFile = @"C:\Temp\Trade Files\queued\filetest1.txt";
                 string destinationFile = @"C:\Temp\Trade Files\processed\filetest1.txt";

                 System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile); 
             }
             catch(IOException ex){
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);//"File not found"
             }
         }

         private void button4_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
         {
             OpenFileDialog fileBrowserDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
             //folderBrowserDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
             //folderBrowserDlg.SelectedPath = _filelistlocation;
             fileBrowserDlg.FileName = textBox1.Text;
             DialogResult dlgResult = fileBrowserDlg.ShowDialog();
             if (dlgResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
             {
                 textBox1.Text = fileBrowserDlg.FileName;
                 File_existence.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                 // Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = folderBrowserDlg.RootFolder;
             }
         }

         private void button5_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
         {
             if (!textBox1.Text.Equals(String.Empty))
             {
                 if (System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text).Length > 0)
                 {
                     foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text))
                     {
                         checkedListBox1.Items.Add(file);
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     checkedListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("No file found: {0}", textBox1.Text));
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

The task I need to do is that the files that appear in the checked list box need to usually be moved or copied to another directory. That is fine as I can already do that with what I have coded, but what it does is it will move or copy all of the files in the checked list box. What I want to do is enable the user to only be able to select which files they what to move or copy through checking the checked list box so that only those files will be moved or copied.

EDIT: Could it be checkedListBox.checked items?

Comment: Um, I think you should rework the question and make a clear mission statement. I have read it 3 times and still don't understand where your problem lies. This may be a sign that you don't quite understand either ;-) - So what __exactly__ is the question? - Also: Instead of telling us to ignore the comments you should have taken them out of your post!!

Comment: OK, I will try to simplify. The task I need to do is that the files that appear in the checked list box need to usually be moved or copied to another directory. That is fine as I can already do that with what I have coded, but what it does is it will move or copy all of the files in the checked list box. What I want to do is enable the user to only be able to select which files they what to move or copy through checking the checked list box so that only those files will be moved or copied. You are right that I don't really know how to explain because I don't really understand myself. new to c#

Comment: Looks like you want to loop over `checkedListBox1.CheckedItems` : `foreach( var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                string fn = item.ToString();`
                ..
            } - If you add the `FileInfo` object to the `Tags` of each Item you can work with those as well..

Comment: In the last hour I have managed to something similar to that but I have no idea where to place it in the code. The copy button is button 2 and move button is button 3, I assume somewhere inside here? Also how do the FileInfo and Tags functions work?

Comment: I would put it right in the buttons or in a function `copyAll` and/or `moveAll` called from those buttons. - `FileInfo` is the object class you are using in your code and has many interesting data about the files like dates, size etc.. . `Tag` is a general purpose field most objects offer and while you want a string to display in the listbox it comes handy to have access to all the other information about each file; so instead of discarding it as you do now I would store it and could then for example display info about a selected file.

Comment: It worked finally! Thanks alot